# Inverse of product of operators

Tags: operator-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be bounded operators. Suppose that $A$ does not have inverse and that $A$ and $B$ commutes. How can we  proof that $AB$ does not has inverse?

Comment: If it did, then the inverse of $A$ would be $B(AB)^{-1}$.

Comment: The only way to prove this is to start by contradiction. Suppose that $AB$ has an inverse, and conclude using hypothesis that $A$ has an inverse.

Answer (score 1):

If $AB$ be invertable then, let $(AB)^{-1}= C $ so $ABC=I$ that is $BC$ is inverse of $A$ , which is contradiction.